# KeePass2 auto-type google, and other password systems

Tags: password, keepass

I am going through the process of changing all my passwords using KeePass2, using 256bit encryption, with keyfile held on microSD. In test I cannot seem to get my autotype to work.

I created a shortcut in the keyboard manager

Name: `KeePass Auto-Type`

path: `mono /usr/lib/keepass2/KeePass.exe --auto-type`

according to http://keepass.info/help/v2/setup.html#mono

installed xdotool as needed.

I try to place auto-type password into browser https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth

my KeePass2 entry has the title "Google" username

now when I hit the key to autotype it types a portion of the 64 characters an estimated 16 then attempts to sign in?

Chromium v28.0.1500.71 : Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Could you please expand your question with what browser you use?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to add that as I was heading out the door, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @MadMike Yes I would consider this a duplicate after installing ChromIPass I was able to get it working thank you for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

Installing ChromIPass got this to work.